# Redoing links in bash terminal

Tags: macos, bash

So I just installed emacs version 24 on OS X 10.8 by means of brew package manager, it installed in `/usr/local/Cellar/emacs`. I regularly use the builtin version of emacs version 22, but its in `/usr/bin`.

So there are two things I'd like to know how to do

1. Change it so that the first place that bash looks for is in
   `/usr/local/Cellar` and their bins
2. Just change it so that the bin for emacs in `/usr/bin` calls the bin for
   emacs in `/usr/local/Cellar/emacs/bin`.

These are two separate but related questions.

EDIT: So I did a hack job and just edited the `.bash_profile` and did an export for `/usr/local/Cellar/emacs/24.3/bin` ..but still would like to know how to get one bin to call another one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably better to not touch anything in /{usr/,}{s,}bin. You can use homebrew versions in bash by adding something like this to .bash_profile:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

Putting /usr/local/bin and /usr/local/sbin first in /etc/launchd.conf might have some unexpected side-effects. For example in TextMate many commands stop working if `env ruby` is Ruby 2.0 or 1.9.

Or for example set PATH to `~/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin` and add symlinks to ~/bin/. See [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/580611/69039).

Comment: does the colon in the path URL signify where terminal should look next?